# Cannot parse xml - Error: Non-whitespace before first tag. Line: 0 Column: 1 Char: 4

Tags: xml-parsing, coffeescript

I am writing a simple atom package. When I send a request, server makes a xml response, so I tried parsing it with [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js). However the error occurs:

Error: Non-whitespace before first tag. Line: 0 Column: 1 Char: 4

[err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvm9p.png)

How can I resolve it?
Thank you in advance.

Part of Codes:

```
module.exports = class HatenaBlogPost
~~~

  @hatenaBlogPost = new HatenaBlogPost()

~~~

postEntry: (callback) ->
  draft = if @isPublic then 'no' else 'yes'

  requestBody = """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
           xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
    <title>#{@entryTitle}</title>
    <author><name>#{@getHatenaId()}</name></author>
    <content type="text/plain">
      #{_.escape(@entryBody)}
    </content>
    <updated>#{moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')}</updated>
    <app:control>
      <app:draft>#{draft}</app:draft>
    </app:control>
    </entry>
  """

options =
  hostname: 'blog.hatena.ne.jp'
  path: "/#{@getHatenaId()}/#{@getBlogId()}/atom/entry"
  auth: "#{@getHatenaId()}:#{@getApiKey()}"
  method: 'POST'

request = https.request options, (res) ->
  res.setEncoding "utf-8"
  body = ''
  res.on "data", (chunk) ->
    body += chunk
  res.on "end", ->
    callback(body)


request.write requestBody
request.end()
```

View:

```
{parseString} = require 'xml2js'

~~~

@hatenaBlogPost.postEntry (response) =>
   parseString response, (err, result) =>
     if err
       atom.notifications.addError("#{err}", dismissable: true)
     else
       entryUrl = result.entry.link[1].$.href
       entry_Title = result.entry.title
       atom.notifications.addSuccess("Posted #{entry_Title} at #{entryUrl}", dismissable: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is the so-called Byte-Order-Mark (BOM), a 3-byte “Zero width no-break space” Unicode character which Windows systems automatically prepend to UTF-8 files. When inspecting your file with a hex editor, the BOM shows up as hex `EFBBBF`.

To fix the issue:

```
var cleanedString = origString.replace("\ufeff", "");
```

See [this article](http://www.multiasking.com/blog/xml2js-sax-js-non-whitespace-before-first-tag/) for more.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, know any other things I could try?

Comment: The link to the article is now broken.

Comment: https://www.apimock.com/blog/20121127_xml2js-sax-js-non-whitespace-before-first-tag

Comment: not clear as in where the solution line is placed?

Answer (score 1):

This was [supposedly fixed at one time in xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/issues/324), but doesn't seem to be currently. Unfortunately, [Benjamin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783452/cannot-parse-xml-error-non-whitespace-before-first-tag-line-0-column-1-cha#36136313) wouldn't work for me. I highly suggest [dos2unix](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man%5Fpages/dos2unix1.html) for the time being.

It's as simple as `dos2unix file`.

If you're on OSX, do `brew install dos2unix`. On RHEL related distros (Fedora, Red Hat, CentOS) try doing `dnf install dos2unix`, and so forth for other distros.

Comment: Is there something like this that I could use for a string instead of a file? And within node?

Comment: There is https://www.npmjs.com/package/dos2unix , though I haven't tried it. You could also execute the dos2unix script from a node script, see https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.6/api/child_processes.html. Particularly, .exec would be useful

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using node-soap along with express and for express I had body parser to parse all inputs as json:

```
bodyparser.json()
```

But, in opposite for SOAP requests we need to send xml so I have added one more body parser as below:

```
app.use(bodyParser.text({type:'text/*'}));
```

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue , i inspect my xml file and see there was in first line a string non xml. i remove this line and it working fine for me.

i am using npm lib to parse xml to json

see screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I was passing a certain tag(lets say "result") as a parameter and upon testing I found that the api was not returning the said tag on incorrect requests and hence the error.

My xmlToJson function was as follows:-

```
var result = this.xmlToJson(xmlString, 'result');
```

My API response on success was something like this:-

```
<response>
 <result>
   everything else
 </result>
</response>
```

And on failure, it was like this:-

```
<response/>
```

The absence of result tag resulted in said error.

EDIT:- To get around the said error and to get failure response, I wrapped xmlToJson function with try-catch block and returned failure message on catch block

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue. I realised that the encoding of xml file was utf-16 and that caused this error. On resaving the file to utf-8 encoding and running the code again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when you are attempting to parse XML on something that is not XML like an js object.

I ran into this same issue because I was using an axios [interceptor](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) to decode an XML body and I was adding the interceptor to axios not an axios instance.

Every HTTP response was executing `xmlParser.parseString` multiple times. The first time it would successfully parse the XML string and save the response body as the parsed object, the second time it would attempt to parse the JS object.

Using an axios instance solved my issue.